# Need help applying MinGW patches for std string, getting unexpected ends

Tags: c++, mingw, std, patch

I'm trying to apply these patches:

http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

So that I can use std string stuff that I should have access to anyways.

I have MinGW 4.7.2, and at first, I tried copying the zip files with no luck.

Now I'm trying to manually apply the patches. I copied the patch information into a file.patch, placed it in the same folder as the file I am patching, and ran

```
patch < file.patch
```

and then I get:

```
 patching file stdio.h
 patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
 Hunk #1 FAILED at 574.
 patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file stdio.h.rej
 patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
```

I made sure that there is no extra white space at the end..

Please help!

Comment: If you created the patch file using a dos editor, it may be missing the trailing line end. Use an editor like vim to make sure that there is a line end at the end of the file. Additionally, make sure that the file uses unix line endings

Comment: Did you try the patch yourself and does it work? If so, would you be kind enough to send me the patch files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, installed the latest mingw from the web-site, downloaded the [patch files](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string) and made sure they were clean.

I applied each one individually, and they worked without issue. There was a warning that it was 'Stripping the trailing CRs from the file', but it worked without issue.

each patch is applied in the appropriate directory; e.g. the `stdio.patch` is applied to `stdio.h` which is in `/mingw/include` using:

```
patch </path/to/stdio.patch
```

ditto for `wchar.patch`

The `os_defines.h` file is found at `/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/mingw32/bits`, and the patch works properly for that one as well.

I created a github with the patches at https://github.com/petesh/mingwpatches.git - you can clone the repository, or download the individual files from there. Each of them should work correctly without more than a complaint about the trailing CR warning.

Comment: How do I download them? I'm only presented with the option of copying what's in them..

Comment: if you don't have github for windows, or poshgit, then you can click on the cloud icon that says zip, which downloads the files in a .zip file. Windows can open zip files natively.

Comment: Thanks. The files patched successfully and I replaced them in the correct folders. I restarted my machine and eclipse still will not allow me to use itoa or t_string. Any ideas??

Comment: Make sure that you have the compiler flag `-std=c++0x` set, otherwise the code will remain commented out, and thus unavailable.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry for late reply.

Comment: If you're using an eclipse project, then edit the project properties; go to `C/C++ Build` -> `Settings` -> `GCC C++ Compiler` -> `Miscellaneous`. In the `Other flags`  box add `-std=c++0x`, making sure it applies to all configurations (otherwise it will compile in debug but not in release for example). If you're using a Makefile, then add `-std=c++0x` to the `CXXFLAGS` variable

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the patch files, you probably need to use the `-c` option to the `patch` command. This tells `patch` that the patch-files are from a context diff.

E.g.

```
$ patch -c < file.patch
```

Comment: I just ran this and I get: 

patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.

Comment: @MattM Try the `-u` option instead.

Comment: I get the same error again as I did in my original post. Also tried both.