# Applying a Patch to a library using MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, patch

There's a similar[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991290/need-help-applying-mingw-patches-for-std-string-getting-unexpected-ends)  It's on the below link.

I have been given a patch on an email and I need to create a patch file.  I have just pasted the contents into a text file and saved it as 'All Files' as file.patch.    As far as I can tell this is correct.

This patch will apply to multiple files in a library.

I'm not sure how to apply the patch.  I'm guessing that this is done using MinGW but I'm not sure how.  I have set the above directory to the library in the command line like this..

```
cd c:\library
```

I place the patch file in this libraries base director and write the name of the patch.

```
file.patch
```

When I do this (I have tortoise svn installed on my pc) a the patch file opens up with a bunch of colors (Red/Yellor/Green) highlighting some of the text in the file.

Does this mean the patch automatically applies or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

I can't put the patch on the internet but the explanation above is clear.

If I have it all wrong would someone mind explaining how I apply a patch using MinGW on Windows?   Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639036/apply-a-patch-file-in-windows-using-mingw

Comment: Yes I was about to add that link to this thread but I can't make any sense of it.  For example, what does this mean? "patch </path/to/stdio.patch" ?   This post isn't even about patching other libraries, it's about patching MinGW.

Comment: [`patch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) is a unix program for patching files. The link I posted shows how to install an equivalent for a Windows MinGW installation. `patch < /path/to/stdio.patch` tells `patch` to apply `stdio.patch` found in the directory `/path/to/`. The patch file contains the information about which files to make the changes to